# Can I build an electrical pole structure to hold a power wire into my property?

Tags: electrical, power, underground, pole

The power pole to my house is at the back right corner of the property.  However, it's a little outside my property line.  I wanted to run a power line straight down along the pole and into the ground but then I would need an easement since it's actually in someone else's property.

So, can I run the line from the power pole to another pole that is within my property line, then run the line to the ground.  Then run it underground all the way to my house?  Basically, can I build a pole structure to hold the wire into my property?  Maybe even a little shed or something, if I have to.

I don't want to run the line straight from the pole to the house because I will plant some trees that will be directly under the line.

Option:  I also have a garage that is in the back left corner of the property.  I guess, I could also run the power line to the garage (50' run), have a main panel in the garage, then use the house as a sub panel?  The garage is currently powered by the house with an underground wire.  I don't know the gauge on the wire.

Back Right Corner of Property[image]

Back Right Corner of Property[image]

From Backyard to Front Right Corner View[image]

Comment: It looks like you already have overhead service. Are you trying to add an additional service, or to modify the existing service? Have you contacted your service provider? They may provide you with documentation describing what they expect, as far as how the pole is to be erected.

Comment: Here the utility is responsible for the lines up to the meter on the house. Therefore, they would be responsible for what you're proposing to add/change so they should be involved.

Comment: The utility company was not helpful in providing information as to the requirements for a power pole.  They only mentioned putting the wire underground with an easement.

Comment: If you are in such bad neighbor relations with your immediate neighbors that you can't get an easement for what looks to be 10 feet for underground at the very back corners of the properties, I'd seriously suggest moving.

Comment: I was looking for more information on building code for a power pole in my backyard. If I can build a garage then connect service to it, then why not build a power pole structure then connect service to it?  Maybe even a little shed with a foundation.  Just an idea that I thought would be reasonable to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the main service to the garage is probably the most practical option if an easement for full underground is impossible. You will almost certainly need to change the feed wire between the garage and the house for that approach, but that's similar to what you would need to do for an underground feed anyway.

Probably most practical to actually establish new service at the garage and then disconnect the old service to the house, to minimize disruption. (i.e., as opposed to "actually move it") but again, it will depend on your utility's policies and procedures.

Answer (score 10):

Check with your utility to see if they have a program to bury your service line.  My company (FPL) has [a program](https://www.fpl.com/reliability/underground-conversions/process.html) where they will give you the conduit to bury along with instructions.  Once everything is set up and meets their standards, they will bring the lines down the pole for you.  There is a fee, of course.  For FPL in my area, it would cost around $580 plus the cost of an electrician (and permits) you must hire to rearrange the meter.

Answer (score 1):

Normally they will only hang their wire on their pole, set in an easement.

Your first option "run a power line straight down along the pole" is still your first option. The utility must already have easements to access the pole that would in all likelihood cover burial to your yard. In my State they even need an easement for the overhead to cross neighbors air space. You really need to check with your utility engineering department.